# How do i wait for onServiceConnected before going forward

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service

In my application, I have a button which binds to a service, on clicking of a button.

```
SomeObject mObject = null;
bindService(new Intent(IServiceRunner.class.getName()), mServiceRunnerConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
if(mSomeObject != null) {
...
//SOME_CODE_1 
...
}
```

While in the onServiceConnected method of mServiceRunnerConnection, I am instantiating an object as follows:

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        mSomeObject = IServiceRunner.Stub.asInterface(service);
}
```

But after calling the bindService() I am using this mSomeObject. Problem is this instantiation is taking little while to happen, by that time my code fails, and I cannot execute SOME_CODE_1

I know it would be best if I write SOME_CODE_1 inside onServiceConnected() method itself, but due to various restriction I cannot do that.

How do I wait for this mSomeObject to be instantiated before moving forward from bindService() call?

I tried the following:

```
SomeObject mObject = null;
try{
bindService(new Intent(IServiceRunner.class.getName()), mServiceRunnerConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
Thread.sleep(3000);
}catch(Exception e){
}
if(mSomeObject != null) {
...
//SOME_CODE_1 
...
}
```

But this is not at all working (as expected). Please suggest a way to do that.

Comment: yes you are right: write SOME_CODE_1 inside onServiceConnected(), there are no other ways

Comment: define a true bool value. When mSomeObject is done, set the value false. when you wait to  mSomeObject, use while(value){};

Comment: @ozi and you will wait forever as onServiceConnected will never be called,  don't do that

Comment: @pskink also you can keep time count in while right? if longtime > 5sec. break; and continue with null

Comment: @ozi,  no, it will not work, you cannot block the thread after binding to a service

Comment: @pskink is this loop binding with a service ?

Comment: @ozi no,  i assume you are looping afer binding,  right?